# How to temporary disable Option 2 (ENDRQS) of the System Request menu

Tags: ibm-midrange

I found this link that shows how one can disable the Option 2 of the System Request Menu.

```
https://www.itjungle.com/2004/10/27/monitoring-for-system-request-menu-option-2/
```

I couldn't quite understand how it works, but I tried it and it works. Now, my question is how can I undo it?  Below is an example program to better describe what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
         PGM                                                     

         /* disable the system request option 2 by making it a request-processing program */                                                       
         SNDPGMMSG  MSG('Request msg') TOPGMQ(*EXT) MSGTYPE(*RQS)
         RCVMSG     PGMQ(*EXT) MSGTYPE(*RQS) RMV(*NO)            
          
         /* call my 2FA program and do not allow ENDRQS by monitoring for CPF1907 */  
TWOFA:                                                               
         CALL       PGM(TWOFA)              
         MONMSG     MSGID(CPF1907) EXEC(GOTO CMDLBL(TWOFA))      

         /* OK, 2FA is done. Now, how do I enable the system request option 2 ???????  */  
          . . . .
          . . . . 
         ENDPGM
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the request message you placed on the MSGQ...

`rcvmsg pgmq(*ext) msgtype(*rqs) rmv(*YES)`

Comment: I've tried that and for some unknown reason it took me to the command entry screen. It error out if I press F3 to exit the command entry screen. Anyway, I found out that once the program ended, the effect goes away automatically.  So, I ended up created a dummy program to call it.  Once the actual program ended and control is back to the dummy program, the effect of ENDRQS automatically went away.